# Swift recursive enum enters infinite loop in constructor

Tags: swift, recursion, enums, infinite-loop, recursive-datastructures

I've created a recursive `enum` in Swift that compiles without errors or warnings, but which enters an infinite loop when I try to instantiate it:

```
enum Tree<T> {
    case Leaf(T)
    case Branch(T, [Tree<T>])
}

Tree.Leaf(0) // enters infinite loop
Tree.Branch(0, []) // enters infinite loop
```

The infinite loop occurs upon instantiation, not upon printing or any other use of the instance.  Even if nothing is ever done with the result, `Tree.Leaf(0)` still runs forever.  Just to be clear: the infinite loop occurs at runtime, not compile time, but occurs *immediately* upon instantiation.

Strangely, the following very similar data structure works perfectly:

```
enum WorkingTree<T> {
    case Leaf(T)
    case Branch([WorkingTree<T>]) // notice the lack of a `T` in this case
}

WorkingTree.Leaf(0) // works fine
WorkingTree.Branch([.Leaf(1), .Leaf(2)]) // works fine
```

Perhaps even more strangely the following data structure *also* works perfectly:

```
enum ConcreteTree {
    case Leaf(Int)
    case Branch(Int, [ConcreteTree])
}

ConcreteTree.Leaf(0) // works fine
ConcreteTree.Branch(0, []) // works fine
```

Why is my original data structure entering an infinite loop when I try to instantiate it, while these other almost identical data structures are not?

**EDIT:**

In the Swift REPL, the problem seems to be dependent on whether or not the instantiation occurs in the same "block" as the type declaration.  If I type the following into the Swift REPL:

```
1> enum Tree<T> {
2.     case Leaf(T)
3.     case Branch(T, [Tree<T>])
4. } // press enter, declare type
5> Tree.Leaf(0) // separate command to the REPL
```

then it fails with an infinite loop.  However if I enter them as part of the same statement:

```
1> enum Tree<T> {
2.     case Leaf(T)
3.     case Branch(T, [Tree<T>])
4. } // press down arrow, continue multiline command
5. Tree.Leaf(0) // part of the same command
```

Then it does not enter an infinite loop, and works as expected.

What could be going on?

**EDIT 2**:

Things have gotten even stranger.  The following code compiles and runs, but enters an infinite loop at a very unexpected point:

```
enum Tree<T> {
    case Leaf(T)
    case Branch(T, [Tree<T>])
}

let test = Tree.Leaf(0)
print("Milestone 1") // prints

switch test {
    case .Leaf(_): print("Milestone 2") // prints
    default: print("This should never be called")
}

func no_op<T>(x: T) {}

no_op(test) // infinite loop entered here
print("Milestone 3") // DOES NOT print

no_op(Tree.Leaf(0))
print("Milestone 4") // DOES NOT print
```

what could possibly be deferring the infinite loop until that `no_op` call?

Answer (score 5):

You forgot to say `indirect`:

```
enum Tree<T> {
    indirect case Leaf(T)
    indirect case Branch(T, [Tree<T>])
}
```

I'm a little surprised that the code compiled without it; I'd suggest filing a bug report.